# Ошибка при загрузке файлов Yii2:Call to undefined method UploadForm::formName()

Tags: php, yii2, fileupload

Я использую виджет kartik yii2-widget-fileinput. 
Во вью вставил следующий код:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'photo')->widget(FileInput::classname(),['options' => ['accept' => '@yii/files/*'],'pluginOptions' => ['uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/candidate/create']),],]); ?>
```

Контроллер:

```
        $modelFileWidget = new \frontend\models\forms\UploadForm();
        $modelFileWidget->photo = UploadedFile::getInstance($modelFileWidget, 'photo');
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        if ($modelFileWidget->upload()) {
            return ['error' => null];
        }
        return $this->render('create',[
        'model'         => $form,
        'modelFileWidget'=> $modelFileWidget,
        'cities'      => ArrayHelper::map($this->cityService->getAll(),'id','name'),
        'skills'        => ArrayHelper::map($this->skillService->getAll(),'id','name'),
    ]);
```

Модель:

```
class UploadForm {

/**
 * @var UploadedFile
 */
public $photo;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['photo'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => ['jpg', 'png']],
    ];
}

public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $this->photo->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@app').'/web/img/' . $this->photo->baseName . '.' . $this->photo->extension);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

В результате загрузки файла получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
Exception 'Error' with message 'Call to undefined method frontend\models\forms\UploadForm::formName()'
```

Я нашел решение похожего вопроса, но так и не понял как его применить [work with uploaded file in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841761/work-with-uploaded-file-in-yii2)
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сообщении об ошибке у вас написано, что не найден метод `formName()`, который в свою очередь находится в классе `yii\base\Model`. Вероятно вы забыли отнаследоваться от этого родительского класса в `UploadForm`.

```php
namespace frontend\models\forms;

use yii\base\Model;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
    //..
}
```